# What project types in Visual Studio 2013 would you use to create this structure

Tags: asp.net-web-api, n-tier-architecture

I am working on a new project and instead of creating a single project with the UI and Web Services in the same project I want to separate them into two projects. Like the image.

[image]

What project types in Visual Studio 2013 would you use to do this. I know that I can do everything by hand but...

I have tried the WebAPI project type but it assumes everything in 1 project.
I know someone else has wrestled this issue so I would appreciate your input.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Mr. Beam missed the point of the question in that Mr. Washington is asking about the project types to create shared services that are called by and UI type project.

I think just creating an empty project with the WebAPI inclusion would be what you want.  You could then to REST calls to your service layer project with no other overhead.

JD

Comment: You could still create this as a single solution. You could run the site in the background (standalone) and attach to the process and still get a cohesive dev/debug env within the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be confusing "projects" with "solutions". It sounds like you should just start with a Blank Solution and develop out the different projects. There's no reason why all of these couldn't live within the same solution.